# Software to trigger a digital camera to take stop-motion photos?

Tags: mac, software-rec

I want to use my MacBook Pro to trigger a digital camera (Sony DSC-R1) to take a photo every 30 seconds.

What's the best Mac software to do this?

And, is the sofware specific to the camera or should it work for any digital camera that's connected to the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [iStopMotion 2](http://www.boinx.com/istopmotion/overview/). It has 3 versions that allow you to choose how many features you want and it provides a [wide range of cameras](http://www.boinx.com/istopmotion/overview/videovsstill/) that it supports.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Image Capture application can do this. Under File/Take picture, choose 'automatically every...'

Answer (score 0):

This might sound crazy but with QuickTime X and older QuickTimes that support timeline editing you can just delete all the frames you don't want and save the file. So you record the whole stream of you working on your stop motion set (with a built in iSight?) and then delete the parts where your hands are in the frame. Or if you're hopping around the room, where your feet are on the floor. Then you only have the frames you want.

Tedious? yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play it may be worth picking up a Triggertrap mobile dongle and either messing around with one of their free App's, or alternatively writing something yourself using the [PyTt](http://mark0.net/code-pytt-e.html)  module.